# Why is the value obtained by using the lengthof instruction in the process wrong？

Tags: masm32

I tried to use "lengthof" instruction in my "findLargest" PROC to obtain the array length, but got the wrong value (the value is 1), but in "Main" PROC it gets the length right.

CODE:

```
findLargest PROC STDCALL PUBLIC USES ECX ESI numPtr:PTR SDWORD
     local leng:sdword, count:sdword;
     mov dword ptr [leng],lengthof numPtr;  here
     ret 4;
findLargest ENDP
```

Comment: `LENGTHOF` is a compile-time operator. It can not be used in the way you're trying to use it.